# Custom User Request conflict with Orchestra\Html\Form on validation

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Orchestra Html Form with `Laravel 5.8` to generate forms for my custom CMS. In order to validate User requests, I created a UserRequest class which has the rules, messages and the authorize method in order to validate the form submission. If the validation fails, for example, email. unique validation fails, I get an error instead of going back to the view with the validation messages: Method `Orchestra\Html\Form\FormBuilder::__toString()` must not throw an exception, caught ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object.
I also use Orchestra form for other models, but User is the only one with its own custom request and the only model that generates this issue, so the conflict must be with the User Request, I guess. I can't figure out what's wrong.

I dumped the variables on the view, and they seem to be correct.
The `form()` method on the model also works fine, but when the form renders on the view after a validation error, it crashes.

```
"orchestra/html": "^3.5",
Laravel 5.8
```

MODEL:

```php
public function form()
{
    return Form::of('users', function ($form) {
        $attributes = [
            'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
        ];
        $form->attributes($attributes);
        $form->submit = $this->exists ? 'Guardar' : 'Criar';
        $form->fieldset(function ($form) {
            $form->control('select', 'role', function ($control) {
                $control->field(function ($row) {
                    $val = old('role') ?? $this->roles()->first();
                    return "<select class='form-control input-with-feedback' name='role' required>".Role::selectRole($val)."</select>";
                });
            });
            $form->control('input:text', 'nome', function ($control) {
                $control->field(function ($row) {
                    $val = old('name') ?? $this->name ?? '';
                    return "<input type='text' class='form-control input-with-feedback' name='name' value='".$val."' required>";
                });
            });
            $form->control('input:email', 'email', function ($control) {
                $control->field(function ($row) {
                    $val = old('email') ?? $this->email ?? '';
                    return "<input type='email' class='form-control input-with-feedback' name='email' value='".$val."' required>";
                });
            });
            $form->control('input:password', 'password', function ($control) {
                $control->field(function ($row) {
                    return "<input type='password' class='form-control input-with-feedback' name='password' value='$row->password' required>";
                });
            });
            $form->control('input:password', 'repetir password', function ($control) {
                $control->field(function ($row) {
                    return "<input type='password' class='form-control input-with-feedback' name='password_confirmation' value='$row->password_confirmation' required>";
                });
            });
            $form->control('input:file', 'avatar', function ($control) {
                $control->field(function ($row) {
                    $default_img = $this->avatar ?? 0;
                    $val = "<input type='file' class='form-control input-with-feedback' name='avatar' ><input type='hidden' name='avatar' value='".$default_img."'>";
                    if ($this->avatar != NULL){
                        $val .= "<label class='col-md-3 control-label d-block mt-2 mb-0'>Imagem atual:</label><img src='".\CompGallery::getImageFullUrl($this->avatar, '_avatar')."'><label class='control-label  mt-2 mb-0 mx-2'>Apagar Imagem</label><input type='checkbox' name='delete_image' value='on'>";
                    }
                    return $val;
                });
            })->label('Avatar'); 
            $form->control('input:checkbox', 'active', function ($control) {
                $control->field(function ($row) {
                    $val = old('active') ? 'checked' : $this->active ? 'checked' : '';
                    if (is_null($this->active)) $val = 'checked';                     
                    return "<label class='switch'><input type='hidden' value='0' name='active'><input type='checkbox' class='form-control input-with-feedback col-md-4' name='active' id='ativo' value='1' ".$val."><span class='slider round'></span></label>";
                });
            })->label('Ativo');
        });
    });
}
```

REQUEST:

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'role' => 'required',
        'name' => 'required|string|max:50',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:50|unique:users,email,'.$this->id,
        'password' => 'required|string|min:8|confirmed',
        'active' => 'required',
    ];
}

/**
 * Get the error messages for the defined validation rules.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'name.required' => 'O nome é obrigatório',
        'email.required'  => 'O email é obrigatório',
        'email.unique'  => 'O email já existe',
        'password.required'  => 'A password é obrigatória',
        'password.confirmed' => 'As passwords não coincidem'
    ];
}
```

VIEW:

```xml
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7 module-form">
        {!! $form !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

> ERROR MESSAGE: Method Orchestra\Html\Form\FormBuilder::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: The error is clear. You're trying to get the property of a non object. Somewhere in your code you're doing `$var->something` when `$var` is either `null`, an `array`, or well, **not an object**. Try commenting out each `$form->control(...)` in turn and see if you can pinpoint the error.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to find the error in the roles section.